# Why does ARM template ignore apiVersion in VS2019?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Using visual studio 2019 ARM ResourceGroup deployment project:

When trying to use Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments.scope with .apiVersion "2021-04-01-preview" the deployment is failing, stating that: `The api-version '2017-05-10' used to deploy the template does not support 'Scope' property. Please use api-version '2019-05-01' or later to deploy the template.`

The ARM template is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountBlobContributorRoleId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dataFactoryManagedIdentityName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('dataFactoryManagedIdentityName'), '-', parameters('storageAccountBlobContributorRoleId'))]",
      "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', '/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "[parameters('dataFactoryManagedIdentityName')]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "DataLake Data Factory Managed Identity Blob Contributer Assignment"
      },
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[parameters('storageAccountBlobContributorRoleId')]",
        "principalId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('dataFactoryManagedIdentityName'))]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Am I looking at the wrong thing, and there is another Api version reference somewhere else that I need to change? could it be the AzureRM version etc? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a version of the PS script that comes with the VS Azure Resource Group project... and that's still using the AzureRM cmdlets, then that's likely the problem.

The apiVersion referenced in the error message is not related to an apiVersion in your template but the apiVersion used to deploy the template.  That version is baked into the PS cmdlets so the only way to change it is to update the cmdlets.  AFAIKI there is no AzureRM version of the cmdlets that support that apiVersion.  A few things you can try:

1. this is a similar script to the one used by VS but uses the new cmdlets.  IDK if you can invoke it from VS but you can run it on the cmd line to see if it solves the problem:
   https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/Deploy-AzTemplate.ps1
2. Instead of using the scope property, use the [more complex] extension resource format on the roleAssignment

```json
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(variables('storageAccountName'), '/Microsoft.Authorization/', variables('roleAssignmentName'))]"
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    }
```

Somewhat unrelated, but your roleAssignment name should be a guid() with the seed of principal, roleDef and scope (storageAccount) so that it's sufficiently unique in your tenant.

Comment: You are my hero.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the need for roleAssignment to be a guid. I've market this answer as the correct one.